# Convert string date from UTC to AEST

Tags: google-sheets, timezone

I'm importing submissions from a DUDA contact form into google sheets but the time stamp is coming across as a string in the wrong time zone (2020-11-16 23:26:29 UTC). As I can't change the form settings to convert the time zone automatically, is there a formula that I can use to do this every time a new submission is saved to the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your post where (i.e., in which sheet or column) your incoming data is. However, it is best practice never to add anything to a form-intake sheet. Rather, you should do manipulations in another sheet (even if you wind up hiding that sheet from view afterward), and then reference that conversion sheet elsewhere.

That said, supposing that your form-intake sheet is named "Form Reponses 1" and that your UTC dates are coming in *as text* into A2:A, you can try this formula in cell 1 of an otherwise empty column in another sheet:

```
=ArrayFormula({"Header"; IF('Form Reponses 1'!A2:A="",, DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT('Form Reponses 1'!A2:A,"^(.+) ")) + TIMEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT('Form Reponses 1'!A2:A," (.+) ")) + (10/24) )})
```

You can replace "Header" with a more meaningful header.

The results will likely come across as numbers in the 40,000 range with an extended decimal amount. This is the raw date/time format. Just set **Format > Number** for the column to whatever data/time format you prefer.

Comment: Hi Erik,

Yes I think you're right in the fact that I haven't explained myself very well. Let me try this again.
I have a contact form on my website that feeds all submissions into a google docs spreadsheet. Each field on the form gets placed into it's own column. The 1st column "A" is a date stamp. However, my timezone is AEST but the data is placed into the column as UCT as shown above. How can I set it up so that the data in that column is changed from YY-MM-DD T UTC to DD-MM-YY T AEST? The new time can be in a new column as long as it's AEST. I hope that helps.

Comment: @Zealix_Alpha, the formula I provided and explained above does what you are asking. Put it into the top cell of an empty column and make sure the sheet name matches your actual sheet name in each instance (or remove the sheet name instances altogether if you're going to go against my advice and put it in the same sheet that receives the contact form info). It should give you the result you requested. There is no way for me to TEST it, of course, because you haven't shared a link to your sheet.

Comment: Hi Erik, as requested, here is a copy of the link. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J8VHUp7nzYdA5WmuxuqnTDTanz8TUBQ8CQAYEPH0oJM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Zealix_Alpha, your sheet is "View Only," so I can't make any direct changes to it. But the formula is doing exactly what you asked. However, you need to move it up to cell J1 (from J2 where you have it now). And you need to format Column J (Format > Number) as some date-and-time format (where it's now formatted to only show you the date portion). If you click on one of the result cells, however, and look in the formula bar, you'll see that the correctly adjusted date and time are there.